# Spawn Blueprint Class with input parameters C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am fairly new to UE4 development so apologies if I am missing something obvious.

I am trying to convert a system from blueprints to C++. In an attempt to convert the SpawnActor node, I found that I am unable to provide input parameters like in the image below where ‘Index’ is a custom input.

[image: SpawnActor Node]

In other places, to resolve this issue, I have used BeginDeferredActorSpawnFromClass, used an initialise function to provide parameters, then call FinishSpawningActor. This has worked where I am calling a C++ class.

In this case however, the actor I want to spawn is a blueprint class which is a child based on a C++ class. I am unable to implement BeginDeferredActorSpawnFromClass for this, and therefore am not sure how to pass my parameter to this.

For extra context, in the project there can be multiple characters spawned in the world. I want to pass the index of the character in order to set the material colour of each individual character using the nodes shown below.

[image: Purpose for passing parameter]

I am able to achieve this by spawning the BP character using:

```
Character = GetWorld()->SpawnActor(...)
Character->Index = Index
```

And then using EventTick instead of EventBeginPlay but feel this is a bad solution. I would appreciate if someone could advise how to initialise the spawned actor with the required parameter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid. `SpawnActorDeferred` is the function which serves the purpose required.